# hay un limite de filas para una tabla usando el plugin de jquery dataTable?

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatables

Estoy usando datatable para mostrar registros que se consultan a una base de datos por medio de un servicio web, veo que los registros se dibujan correctamente cuando las filas no excedan los 10.000 registros en promedio, a mayor cantidad empiezan los problemas al dibujar la tabla,
la consulta se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
$cliente_ = new nusoap_client($_SESSION['url']);  //se crea variable de session si login es correcto

$parametros_ = array('nit' => $_SESSION['idclient'], 'idpunto' => $idpunt, 'finicial' => $fecini, 'ffinal' => $fecfin);
$respuesta_ = $cliente_->call("wrextipopago", $parametros_);
$respuesta_ = json_decode($respuesta_, true);
$tabla;
```

despues se organizan los datos usando foreach de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach ($respuesta_ as $row_) {
    $locacion = new Locacion();
    $dispensadora = new Dispensadora();
    $seleccion = new Seleccion();
    $producto = new Producto();
    $tipoEntrega = new TipoEntrega();
    $informeTodos = new InforDetTodos();

    $locacion ->setNombre($row_['nompunto']);
    $dispensadora ->setNombre($row_['nombremaq']);
    $dispensadora ->setNumeroSerie($row_['serialmaq']);
    $producto ->setNombre($row_['nitem']);
    $seleccion ->setNombre($row_['numsel']);
    $producto ->setValor($row_['vsel']);
    $producto ->setCosto($row_['costoprod']);
    $informeTodos ->setFecha($row_['fechaventa']);
    $tipoEntrega ->setNombre($row_['tipoent']);
    $locacion ->setDispensadoras($dispensadora);
    $seleccion ->setProducto($producto);
    $informeTodos ->setLocacion($locacion);
    $informeTodos ->setSeleccion($seleccion);
    $informeTodos ->setTipoEntrega($tipoEntrega);

    $tabla = $tabla . '<tr>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->locacion->getNombre() . '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->locacion->dispensadoras->getNombre() . '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->locacion->dispensadoras->getNumeroSerie() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->seleccion->producto->getNombre() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->seleccion->getNombre() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->seleccion->producto->getValor() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->seleccion->producto->getCosto() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->tipoEntrega->getNombre() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '<td>' . $informeTodos->getFecha() .  '</td>';
    $tabla = $tabla . '</tr>';
}
return $tabla;
```

}

y se procesa el return con datatable, como he mencionado, hasta 10.000 filas en promedio va bien pero mas filas empieza a fallar...

Por qué se puede presentar esto??
como lo podria solucionar??

Comment: ¿Realmente alguien va a trabajar con 10,000 o  más filas en pantalla?  ¿No sería mejor optimizar, filtrar, paginar? Cuando presentas una tal cantidad de datos, el código puede ponerse lento por un sin número de motivos: índices de los datos, recursos del servidor, velocidad de la conexión, etc, etc. En cualquier caso, presentar 10.000 filas es algo que habría que cuestionarse.

Comment: El data table usa paginación, en pantalla se ven 20 filas pero igual el total de filas de todas las paginas puede ser x numero... @A. Cedano

Comment: No es una buena practica cargar toda la tabla cuando manejas una gran cantidad de registros.  Lo ideal seria que modifiques tu query para que solo retorne los registros que quieres desplegar en pantalla.

Comment: @alanfcm necesito que si un cliente realiza una búsqueda utilizando un filtro de fecha y selecciona un periodo de tiempo ejemplo un mes, esto cargaría x cantidad de registros, la cantidad de registros dependerá del periodo de tiempo que se seleccione y hay usuarios con gran cantidad de información, como hay columnas en las que se realiza autosuma de todas las celdas se requiere desplegar toda la información solicitada.... lo que requiero es conocer cómo cargar una gran cantidad de filas o si hay un límite de filas para generar una tabla usando datatable...

Comment: @alanfcm podría limitar el rango de fecha pero no a menos de un mes

Comment: No importa si tienes que filtrar tus datos.  Vamos a suponer que escoges un rango de un mes y ese rango te retorna 10000 registros.  Aun asi tu puedes limitar el numero de registros que se retornan usando un LIMIT y OFFSET en tu query.  En cuanto a la autosuma, podrias utilizar otro query diferente que solo retorne la suma.

Comment: @alanfcm  las columnas de la tabla tienen campos para filtrar datos ademas del filtro general que busca en toda la tabla, cada vez que escribo en los campos de filtro la autosuma se ejecuta para actualizar los totales de las columnas que estoy sumando... con un query para la suma no se presentaría problema al sumar los valores siempre que se filtre en algún campo??

Comment: Me parece que los filtros en las columnas deberian de actuar igual que el filtro general.  No importa si filtras un solo campo, eso te va a afectar los registros que se retornan.  Si usas esa logica, el query de la autosuma siempre se ejecutaria con los registros retornados, sin importar como se obtuvieron.